# Rendering connect-flash message in HTML instead of EJS with PassportJS

Tags: javascript, html, express, passport.js, ejs

So I've been going through some basic examples for implementing local authentication using PassportJS, and I successfully build a working version. However, instead of using EJS as my template, I was hoping to keep my pages in pure HTML. I'm stuck when it comes to trying to figure out how to access my connect-flash message in HTML.

Route Snippet:

```
 app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect : '/profile',  section
    failureRedirect : '/login', /
    failureFlash : true 
}));
```

Passport Strategy:

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({

    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true 
},
function(req, email, password, done) { 
    User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {

        if (err)
            return done(err);


        if (!user)
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); 
        if (!user.validPassword(password))
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); 
        return done(null, user);
    });

}));
```

Snippet of EJS that can correctly load the flash messages:

```html
<body>
<div class="container">

<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

    <h1><span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span> Signup</h1>

    <!-- show any messages that come back with authentication -->
    <% if (message.length > 0) { %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
    <% } %>

    <!-- LOGIN FORM -->
    <form action="/signup" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Signup</button>
    </form>
```

Basically, I want to know how I can access the <%= message %> object using pure HTML/js...if this is possible? I'm not sure how to assign a variable to this because I don't quite understand how it is passed into the .ejs when it is rendered.

Sorry for my noobiness when it comes to this stuff, and thank you!

Comment: Think of EJS like PHP: it's server-side code that outputs the client-side HTML. You're not gonna be able to access `<%= message %>` on the client side--only its result. Now, if you _want_ the result, you can do: `<input type="hidden" value="<%= JSON.stringify(message) %>">` and grab the value using javascript.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!